# Config file in R package

Tags: r, package, config

I would like to include a "config" file in an R package that I am building. However, what I would like to achieve is for the file to be loaded on memory every time the package is loaded and for it to be available in the package installation folder available for the users to change upon demand.

For example, if a user of this package wants to modify the config file, he could simply find it in his "library/package" directory, make the required changes, reload the package and see the effects of his change.

I have implemented the following solution. Adding the config file in inst/extdata and reading it using read.csv and assigning it to a global variable as part of the .onLoad function. In this case the users of the package would be able to apply changes without rebuilding the package.

This is what I have in my zzz.R file:

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {

  config_resources <<-
    read.csv(file = system.file("extdata", "config.csv", package = "TSTpkg"),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
```

Is this the right approach to achieve what I want to do? If not, what would the right approach be? Finally, is there any way to make this data available internally while still maintaining the ability for the user to change this on demand? Something similar to the sysdata.rda but without the need to rebuild the package for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I don't think you should have a config file in your package (although you don't explain why you want one). Maybe, you should use `options` or something like this instead? See `https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/R/onLoad.R` for an example.

Comment: @Roland The package will be accessing data from a directory/file structure that is subject to change from time to time. I thought of this file as an agile/straightforward way for the naive user to make modifications if needed. Could you please elaborate or provide any references as to why I should not have a config package in my package?

Comment: Telling a user to navigate to their library folder (already a problem for many) and thereafter inside an installed package structure does not seem straightforward to me. It would be preferable to allow the user to import data from an arbitrary location (maybe coupled with an easy possibility of exporting the default file as a template).

Comment: Does the [config](https://github.com/rstudio/config) package provide any of useful building blocks for you?